# Выскакивает generic array creation в Iterator (java)

Tags: java, итераторы, linked-list

Задача состоит в том, чтобы сделать коллекции ArrayList, LinkedList по-своему.
Я их сделал. Потом придумал сделать так чтобы они еще и в forech работали. Начал читать по Itrable. Свой ArrayList как-то сделал, а в LinkedList начала высскакивать ошибка generic array creation. Не знаю как с ней справиться.
[image: Мой итератор]

[image: Моя нода для LinkedList]

Вот код:
*Iterator

```
 @Override
public Iterator<T> iterator() {
    final Node[] node = new Node[]{first};

    return new Iterator<>() {
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return node[0].next != null;
        }

        @Override
        public T next() {
            T element = (T) node[0].data;
            node[0] = node[0].next;
            return element;
        }
    };
}
```

- Node

  ```
  class Node {

  private Node next, prev;
  private Object data;

  Node(T data, Node next, Node prev) {
      this.data = data;
      this.next = next;
      this.prev = prev;
  }

  void setNextLink(Node next) {
      this.next = next;
  }

  void setPrevLink(Node prev) {
      this.prev = prev;
  }   
  }
  ```

Comment: Если нужен код моего LinkedList, могу скинуть

Comment: Не нужно оформлять код картинкой, никто не будет переписывать его к себе или присматриваться, что же там у вас такое, оформляйте вопросы правильно. Перенести весь код текстом иначе помощи не дождетесь. Большинство пользователей проходят мимо таких вопросов.

Answer (score 0):

У вас нет правильного конструктора `Node`.
Я не знаю, что у вас является `first`, допустим, это ваш объект, тогда вам надо сделать такой конструктор

```
Node(){}

Node(Object data) {
    this();
    this.data = data;
}
```

Comment: Что это? Зачем???